# A story involving a spaceship with a non-euclidian interior, that melds the minds of its occupants

Tags: story-identification

For some reason I cannot remember a motley crew assembles in the ship including aliens whose word for god includes both devil and god.

I read it sometime in the 70s, so it could have been written any time between 1950 and 1980.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: When did you read this book? Do believe it was new then? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: Read in the 70s, could have been written any time between 1950 and 1980. No memory of the cover. Sorry, I only tend to remember storyline.

Comment: "Voyager in Night" by C J Cherryh sounds similar, in which the crew of the mining ship *Lindy* are captured and experimented on by a bizarre alien ship, now only operated by artificial beings since the crew died long before. Sound right?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like David Gerrold's Space Skimmer (1972).

The Empire has fallen!
And we eventually realize that it was the fault of a new system of transport that had been introduced, the 'space skimmers', that were so fast and efficient that they disrupted conventional supply lines; they may have also had a tendency to drive their crews mad — being described as like being inside an Escher drawing (I think would count as 'non-Euclidean').

The story starts with a young man named Mass managing to track one of these ships down, hoping to put it back into service, and we then see him assembling a crew.
I do not remember aliens, per se, but I think there were androids.

Comment: Escher did collaborate with mathematician H.M.S. Coxeter who worked with hyperbolic geometry. Documentary interview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkhuMvFQWz4